# How to send HTTP Request at intervals and Asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, dynamic, httprequest

I've an app with a webview and a uiview showing dynamic content. So I have to keep the uiview content refreshed dynamically with the webserver. I'm new to swift, so I build up this app from a single webview, and the uiview is recently added.

For now I use below stupid code, to keep uiview content sync. Using js do the http request at intervals Asynchronously and call swift code at the same time.

js code,

```
$interval(function()
{
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.66/uidata")
        .success(function(response)
        {
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.startLive.postMessage(response.data);
        }
}, 3000);
```

swift code,

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
  if(message.name == "startLive") {
    startLive(message.body)
  }
}
```

How can I just use native swift code to do the HTTP Request  at intervals and Asynchronously?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use Timer and URLSession which is asynchrously to make it.

```
var timer: Timer?

func startTimer() {

    if timer == nil {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.loop), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func stopTimer() {
    if timer != nil {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}

func loop() {
    let liveInfoUrl = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.66/api/cloud/app/liveInfo/7777")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: liveInfoUrl! as URL) {data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)) ?? "aaaa")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```